# Story about the invention of a mind reader artifact commissioned by Hitler to unmask a traitor

Tags: story-identification, nazis

About twelve years ago, I started to read a story online (in English) from a website that I don't remember. I know for sure that the title of the story was related to a biblical element. At one-third of the story, I had to do a business travel for a couple of weeks during which I lost my luggage including my laptop. Shortly after, I was able to recover my luggage but my laptop. Yes, I lost my laptop!

The story in question was about a senior Nazi scientist who was commissioned by Adolf Hitler to invent an artifact capable of reading the thoughts of the human beings. The purpose of the Fuhrer with this request was to expose a traitor to the Third Reich: a high ranked Nazi officer. Hitler had known about a traitor through a fortuneteller. The scientist managed to invent an artifact with Jewish traits, as a product of his practical experiences in the concentration camps. The invented artifact was described as an old-fashion headset connected to small wooden cubes. This invention which was tested on Hitler's birthday in a private meeting at a retreat house (I am sure it was Hitler's Berghof) full with officers. The traitor was unmasked which triggered a brawl between supporters and opponents of the use of the artifact. Then, amidst the bickering, traitor and invention disappeared.

I remember a passage early in the story. During a rainy morning at the gardens of the Reich Chancellery, where Hitler was walking his dog (Blondi), Hitler asked the scientist if it was possible to grasp information from the brain to know when a man was lying, at which the scientist responded that there were some glands in the brain that wear out when the subject is an honored man or atrophy if the subject is a liar, and the scientist ends by saying something like: animals, however, don’t lie, only bluff.

In the first pages of the story, the scientist uses his 'ideas' (on which the invention shall be based later on) to help German boxer Max Schmeling to defeat the American champion, Joe Louis, then, thanks to the scientist, Schmeling returned to Berlin (aboard the Hindenburg) victorious and glorified as the perfect embodiment of the Aryan race and threatening to the resurgence of the REICH).

Time to time, all these years, I have been googling for this story trying to find it without success.

During Berghof's meeting, I remember reading about Hitler pulling out a coin, a Tyrian shekel (I remember it because it was mentioned Hercules and the eagle), and tossing it to decide something. He said that the coin was the same coin that Jesus Christ grabbed while retorting "Render to Cesar..." and that later on the coin came to the hands of Alexander the Great and finally to his (Hitler) hands.

Comment: Although this is already nicely detailed, you might want to consider going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)